# Comma separated list into a non associated array in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string of emails:

```
$emails = 'email1@example.com, email2@example.com,email3@example.com';
```

and I need a basic array like `[one,two,three]` and not `[0 => 'one', 1 => 'two', 2 => 'three']`. I guess is a non-associative array?

How to do that? I have tried the inbuild 'explode()' PHP function but it creates 0 => one,  ... instad of a a simple array email1,email2,..

Besides, explode has problem when there is a space after the comma, so I have to use `', '` or `','` but can't use both.

What PHP function is the best to convert a list of email addresses into a simple non-associative array? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `array`s supposed to be like this only.

Comment: All items in an array will have a key and a value

Comment: 1) Those two arrays are exactly the same. Every array needs keys! 2) You might want to look at `preg_split()` which is similar to `explode()`, but you then can use a regular expression as delimiter where you can also define that `,` and `,[space]` should be a delimiter

Comment: Run this `<?php $a = ['one','two','three']; print_r($a); ?>` What you want and what you got are **the same thing**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can remove spaces by `str_replace`

```
$emails = str_replace(' ', '', $emails);
```

> and I need a basic array like [one,two,three] and not [0 => 'one', 1 => 'two', 2 => 'three']. I guess is a non-associative arr

In php *simple* arrays has numeric keys, so it's correct